# How to properly call many functions with the same args?

Tags: python, function

I have some question:

How to call multiple functions (10,100, 1000 functions) with the same argument?

Just an example:

```
def function1(arg):
return arg

def function2(arg):
    return arg*2

def function_add_arg(arg):
    return np.sum(arg)


def call_functions(values):

    result = (function1(values), function2(values), function_add_arg(values))
    return result

values = [1, 2, 3, 4]
result_tuple = call_functions(values)
```

What if I have 1000 functions with different names? (Function_a, f2, add)
So you cannot use:

```
result = (eval(f'function_{i}({values})') for i in range(100))
```

My solution for this example (it's not the best one, it's just for showing my idea):

```
def call_functions(function_list, values):
    result = tuple((function(values) for function in function_list))
    return result

function_list = [function1, function2, function_add_arg]
values = [1, 2, 3, 4]

result_tuple = call_functions(function_list, values)
```

But how do it correctly? (especially if I will call more functions)

Different solution is to use **kwargs except function list.

Some different, better solutions? Decorators?

Regards!

Comment: Why do you say that your solution is not good? The comprehension is IMO the right way to go (maybe use a list comprehension instead of a generator one wrapped in a tuple, but that's all I'd change).

Comment: How do you decide which functions to include in your list? That would set the rules for how you can do this without manually listing them all - your last solution seems perfectly fine. You could have a separate module / file with all the functions that should be invoked, import that and create a list of all the functions from that module.

Comment: I would prefer `def call_functions(functions, values): return (function(values) for function in functions)`. Why bother with binding `result` just to return it on the next line, and why a `tuple`? Let the caller decide what to do with the iterable. Also -- it is cleaner to have your `function_list` an explicit argument (which doesn't really need to be a list, so call it something else).

Comment: Thank you for your comments, @MatsLindh, while I write my functions, I can decide. SO solution with decorator is fine for me.
And to be honest I can just delete some function from this list before calling "call_functions".

JohnColeman - You're right. Thank you!
Seems great for me :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could build that list of functions with a decorator:

```
function_list = []
def register(function):
    function_list.append(function)
    return function

@register
def function1(arg):
    return arg

@register
def function2(arg):
    return arg*2

...
```

Comment: How does this work? It would be helpful if you can share the output.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to put all your functions into a separate file with an additional line at the end:

```
def f1(arg):
    ...
def f2(arg):
    ...
.
.
.
def fN(arg):
    ...

functions = {k:v for k,v in vars().items() if '__' not in k}
```

The `functions` variable will contain the name of all your functions that were declared before. I removed the built-in variables that start and end with the double underscores but you can also filter it for a prefix that all your functions are using.
Importing this file will also import the variable that you can use to iterate through and call them with your arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a higher-order function which fixes an input and makes the return value a function of the function that you apply to that input:

```
def fix_input(value):
    def apply(f):
        return f(value)
    return apply
```

Used like:

```
def function1(arg):
    return arg

def function2(arg):
    return arg*2

def function_add_arg(arg):
    return sum(arg)

function_list = [function1, function2, function_add_arg]
values = [1, 2, 3, 4]

apply = fix_input(values)
print([apply(f) for f in function_list])
#[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4], 10]
```

You could also use `apply` with `map`, allowing you to `map` an input over a list of functions. Conceptually, this is what you are doing, though it is a matter of taste if you want to make it explicit in this way.